# Vent hood throwing bedroom breaker

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Let me start by saying that electrical is not my strongest area. With that being said, I'm experiencing an issue where the breaker for two of my bedrooms is thrown approximately a minute or two after the vent hood in the kitchen is turned on. When the breaker goes, the vent hood continues running. This makes me think it's not on the same breaker and, thus, shouldn't be throwing the breaker for the bedrooms. I'm  thoroughly confused by this situation and am very curious to see what some experts might think considering this conundrum.

Comment: Do any of the breakers involved have a TEST button on them?

Comment: Is the breaker for the bedroom an AFCI breaker? It could be that the motor for the vent hood is sending out a transient which is getting through to the AFCI breaker for another circuit. When you are resetting the "breaker" for the bedrooms is this the breaker in the panel or a receptacle in one of the bedrooms? Is it absolutely certain that the vent hood and the bedrooms are on different circuits with different breakers?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, in fact the breaker that keeps getting thrown is the only one with a test button. The remaining ones don't.

Comment: @JimStewart I'm fairly certain it's an AFCI. And the breaker is in the main panel I believe. Which happens to be in one of the bedrooms but also contains the breakers for the rest of the house. And, no, I'm not certain about them being on different circuits with different breakers. I just made an assumption because when the breaker is thrown, the vent hood remains on. But I'm really not an expert in anything electrical lol

Comment: What make and model is the AFCI in question?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It's a Siemens S1624L1125

Comment: @Adam -- does your AFCI have a pair of LEDs on the front? If so, are either or both LEDs lit when the AFCI trips?

Comment: I wonder if a whole house surge protector (DIY cost $150 w/ req'd breaker) would prevent these small spikes from getting from one branch circuit into others and tripping AFCI breakers? http://myhome.eaton.com/eaton-products/surge-protection; https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-Whole-House-Surge-Protector-CHSPT2ULTRA-1/204761136?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD27E%7C27-8_CIRCUIT_PROTECT._DEVICES%7CNA%7CPLA%7c71700000034238981%7c58700003943782709%7c92700031956831781&gclid=Cj0KCQjw77TbBRDtARIsAC4l83nCCJDp8OA2X5XSufefNEIKkqneWMMqqECtNBfEEdMBE_v5Mt7DNH4aAppXEALw_wcB&dclid=CM2u7Zm84twCFUQUgQoduFINdw

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the hood vent motor/lights are connected by a power cord plugged into a standard 120 V plug in the space above the hood. If yours is connected this way, you could get one of these plug in wall surge protectors. I am sure that the intention is to protect against incoming surges, but if it would also protect against outgoing surges, then this might prevent the motor transients from going back to the panel where they could find their way to the AFCI breakers. [GE surge protector wall tap](https://www.grainger.com/product/53TZ09?cm_mmc=PPC:%20Google%20PLA&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!50916810237!!!g!81031474557!&ef_id=Wb6hZAAABW5VfXMN:20180810155732:s) But I am not sure it would be allowed by code or wise to leave a wall tap surge protector in a normally covered location. These devices are presumably more susceptible to failure by overheating and shouldn't be in an enclosed location which is in fact a permanent installation.

A way to test whether a surge protector would stop the tripping (without buying a compact one) would be to lay a standard plug strip with surge protector in the space and fold up its power cord or to temporarily use an extension cord to connect a large surge protector purely as a test to see if the tripping in the bedroom circuit would not occur if the vent hood motor were isolated.

Comment: An EMI filter would work better than a surge protector. Motor transients tend not to be 60Hz sine waves.

Comment: Would this qualify? Tripp-Lite ULTRABLOK428 Direct Plug-in Isobar Surge Suppressor https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA6ZP3KN1393&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC-_-pla-_-Surge+Protectors-_-9SIA6ZP3KN1393&gclid=Cj0KCQjw77TbBRDtARIsAC4l83kZlD-N_YADyCn1v7VuCOMeG1FK8CWpiweCQfvpg63CUY2DSFhvOcIaAjnmEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: I would agree that an EMI or RFI filter would be better but I have found no solution with AFCI faults on motor loads and heavily loaded electronic ballasts what my AHJ allowed was the circuits to be isolated with standard breaker protection after proving things like adjustable beds, oxygen generators and Flouresents caused tripping on top of just about every other motor driven device.